# Determine whether $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{n^2}$ converges uniformly on $[5,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I cannot figure out whether or not $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{n^2}$ converges uniformly over $[5,\infty)$.  My first thought was to try using the Weierstrass M-Test but failed immediately. Is there a general approach for proving the uniform convergence (or lack of) of sums?

Comment: yeah sorry, it is corrected in the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n$, we can find an $x \in [5,\infty)$ for which
$$
|f_n(x) - f(x)| = \left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^2}{n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{n^2}\right| >1
$$
How do we find such an $x$, or show that such an $x$ exists? Why does the above conclusion disprove uniform convergence?

**Hint:** note that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^2}{n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{n^2}\right| =
x^2 \left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\right| = 
x^2 \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\right|
$$

Comment: So from here can we suppose we have $x^2a_n$? I can see that the first part shows that we have the negation of the definition for uniform convergence. I just dont see where to take it

Comment: For any $n$, just choose some $x$ that's bigger than $\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\right|^{-1/2}$

Comment: Is this the typical way of testing when we are unable to use the Weierstrass M-Test?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the best way to think about it. I'd say that proving uniform convergence means finding an $N$ that will permit an arbitrarily small upper bound for $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ for $n>N$, whereas disproving uniform convergence means finding some upper bound $m$ that won't work and finding a pathological value of $x$ for which $|f_n(x) - f(x)|\geq m$ for a given $n$. I'd think of the $M$ test as a "first attempt" which, if it works, will allow you to solve the problem quickly and neatly.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\sum_{n\geqslant 1} x^2n^{-2}=x^2\sum_{n\geqslant 1}n^{-2}$$

Comment: I can see that $\sum_{n\geq 1} x^2n^{-2}$ converges pointwise, say to $a_n$. I suspect it is not Uniform Convergent and negate the definition. But I can't make any headway